# Ripping CDs not working: no id tags

Tags: 12.10, cd-ripping

No cd ripper was working in my Vostro 3550 - 12.10 Quantal. Later on I found out that you do not have to rip CDs anymore in Ubuntu: all you have to do is open the cd and drag all songs (that shows in .wav format) to your desktop. Trouble is: no id tags. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure if WAVE is capable of storing ID3-Tags. You would convert those files anyway to another format because of their size. Either choose FLAC if you need it to be losless or OGG, MP3 or something else.

For converting I use `xcfa` and for tagging I use `puddletag` (which both should be in the Ubuntu repos).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can I rip songs WITH de id tags?

Comment: Confirming: wave can not store ID3 tags. @Carlos question you ask here in comment is answered in the answer: convert/rip to either OGG or MP3.

Answer (score 0):

Sound Juicer will rip cds to mp3 or ogg with ID3 tags.